# Select an item in csv based on value of second column

Tags: python

I'm trying to copy the files to another folder based on my csv. My csv contains the list of files in my folder. But how can I filter it based on the second column? For  example copy only this file if the second column contains "undetected".

Here is my code but I dont know how to filter the files. This copies all my files to another folder.

```
import os
import shutil
import csv

valid_files = set()  # empty set
with open('sha1_vsdt.csv', 'r') as f:
    for rowDict in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
       valid_files |= {rowDict[0] and "Undetected" in rowDict [2] }  # add file name to set
       print(rowDict)  # if desired


dir_src = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\OJT\scanner\\samples_extracted'
dir_dst = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\OJT\scanner\\transfer'
for file in os.listdir(dir_src):
    if file in valid_files:
        src_file = os.path.join(dir_src, file)
        dst_file = os.path.join(dir_dst, file)
        shutil.copy(src_file, dst_file)
```

How do I correct this line?

```
valid_files |= {rowDict[0] and "Undetected" in rowDict [2] }  # add file name to set
```

Example entries of my csv

```
0191a23ee122bdb0c69008971e365ec530bf03f5,aaa,MIME 6010-0
02b809d4edee752d9286677ea30e8a76114aa324,bbb,Microsoft RTF 6008-0
0349e0101d8458b6d05860fbee2b4a6d7fa2038d,ccc,Adobe Portable Document Format(PDF) 6015-0
035a7afca8b72cf1c05f6062814836ee31091559,ddd,Adobe Portable Document Format(PDF) 6015-0
042065bec5a655f3daec1442addf5acb8f1aa824,eee,Undetected
04939e040d9e85f84d2e2eb28343d94a50ed46ac,fff,Undetected
```

Comment: could you provide an example of a rowDict[0] entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `if` should be all that is required:

```
for rowDict in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','):
    if "Undetected" in rowDict[2]:
        valid_files.add(rowDict[0])
```

Comment: shouldn't it be in rowDict[1] ?   it seems rowDict has only 2 entries per line.